# Iterators without STL containers

Tags: c++, iterator

At first sorry about my English.
I`m preparing for my exam and I need to practice iterators, that don`t work with containers.
I would like to input some symbols right to the symbol like '\n' and I have no clue how can I do that.
The problem is I am not able to stop entering symbols.
Hope you can help me.
Sincerely thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ofstream out("name.txt");
    istream_iterator<char> it(cin);
    istream_iterator<char> end_of_stream;
    ostream_iterator<char> fout(out, " ");
    copy (it, end_of_stream, fout);
}
```

Comment: You are iterating until "end of stream" so you must provide it. Usually you can use <CRTL+D> to do so. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110240/why-does-ctrl-d-eof-exit-the-shell

Comment: @SimonKraemer The point is that the OP does not want to iterate to end of stream. `I would like to input some symbols right to the symbol like '\n'`

Comment: @john `The problem is I am not able to stop entering symbols.` But maybe I misinterpreted the question. There's a reason I just wrote a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Fair enough. I only made the comment because the question got closed as a dup on the same interpretation as you made.

Comment: thank you guys, you both helped me so much!

Answer (score 0):

There's no algorithm to copy until you get a particular value (I think) so instead you have to write your own loop.

Like this

```
while (it != end_of_stream && *it != '\n')
{
    fout << *it;
    ++it;
}
```